# Adding column to dataframe where another evaluation is true (Searching dataframes for phone numbers and emails)

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I am attempting to QC some data that I have. I am identifying all of the phone numbers and emails in the entire dataframe.  So far, I can locate them but I want to display the column name and the data from it as well.

I'm not sure how to create columns that contain lists of the data wherever the boolean is true.

Toughts?  The output could also be limited to just lists of the matching number/email instead of the entire set of data for that match.

```
import pandas as pd, re

#create small dummy data set
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'Lineage':['apple', 'square', 'please Gino Mcneill gm@yahoo.com', 'ball', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'ShortDesc':['618-552-2255','Gino Mcneill gm@github.com','',' please call now','if you have trouble you should call 816-455-5599 ASAP' ],
    'LongDesc':['Eesha Hinton', 'for help with product 56789, call 618-578-0055 immediately, or email Gino Mcneill gm@yahoo.com', 'maybe six five today for ever','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

#Find and list where email/phones exist
PEList =(pd.DataFrame({'ID': df['ID'],
               'Email': df.select_dtypes(object)
                          .applymap(lambda x: bool(re.findall(r'(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])', str(x))))
                          .any(axis=1),
               'Phone': df.select_dtypes(object)
                          .applymap(lambda x: bool(re.findall(r'(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?', str(x))))
                          .any(axis=1)}
              ).replace({True: 'x', False: None})
              )
 
cols = ['Email','Phone']
PEList = PEList.dropna(subset=cols, thresh=1)

#Desired Result:
#ID, Email, Phone, E_Col,               E_Col_Dat,                                                                                                                            P_Col,              P_Col_Dat 
#1          x                                                                                                                                                                 ShortDesc           '618-552-2255'
#2   x      x      ShortDesc, LongDec   'Gino Mcneill gm@github.com', 'for help with product 56789, call 618-578-0055 immediately, or email Gino Mcneill gm@yahoo.com'    
#5   x             Lineage,             'please Gino Mcneill gm@yahoo.com'
#26  x      x      Lineage              '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'                                                                                                  Lineage, ShortDesc  '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io', 'if you have trouble you should call 816-455-5599 ASAP'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test for whether each column contains certain regex patterns, and if so, create a new column that replicates the value.  Otherwise, the value in that column's row will be null:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == 'object':
        df.loc[df[col].str.contains('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}') | df[col].str.contains('[A-z0-9]{1,}@[A-z0-9]{1,}'), col+'_phone_or_email'] = df[col]
```

to get

```
   ID  ...                            LongDesc_phone_or_email
0   1  ...                                                NaN
1   2  ...  for help with product 56789, call 618-578-0055...
2   5  ...                                                NaN
3  25  ...                                                NaN
4  26  ...                                                NaN
```

You could also extract each hit using str.extract()

Comment: My demo data isn't as helpful as it could be. I have columns that don't have string values. So this throws an error when it tries to evaluate those. ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!```

Comment: The if statement .dtype == 'object' is meant to exclude anything that isn't a string.  Could you describe what .dtype = 'object' column you have that isn't a string?  There must be a way to filter those out too.  Or you could limit to certain column names.  Worst case, try / except so that you ignore columns that crash when you try to test for a string.